# Python List help: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Tags: python

I am making a list for the main desktop to read what icons are executable and which are not. I keep getting the error:
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Here is a sample of the code:
and yes I have tried EVERYTHING and it just doesn't want to work.

```
    list0 = ["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""]
    for filee in fls:
        if filee.endswith(".jex"):
            jkjk = filee
            icon = os.listdir("/Users/"+getpass.getuser()+"/Desktop/"+jkjk+"/Files/Icon")
            for anything in icon:
                if anything.endswith(".png"):
                    fttts = pygame.image.load("/Users/"+getpass.getuser()+"/Desktop/"+jkjk+"/Files/Icon/"+anything)
                    fttts = pygame.transform.scale(fttts, (48, 48))
                    screen.blit(fttts, (15+aaas, 295+fasdd))
                    print("aaas = "+str(aaas))
                    print("fasdd = "+str(fasdd))
                    fasdd = fasdd + 45

                    if fasdd >= winy-295-63:
                        aaas = aaas + 63
                        fasdd = -280
            jkjk = jkjk+"/Files/Executable"
            jkjk = os.listdir("/Users/"+getpass.getuser()+"/Desktop/"+jkjk)
            for exfilepy in jkjk:
                if exfilepy.endswith(".py"):
                    for o in os.listdir("/Users/"+getpass.getuser()+"/Desktop/"+jkjk+execfilepy):
                        ftttThis[o] = [str(os.listdir("/Users/"+getpass.getuser()+"/Desktop/"+jkjk+execfilepy)[o])]
                    for i in list0:
                        list0[i] = ftttThis[i]
```

.jex is a custom extension and is not causing the problem. it is the list.

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kf9z/Desktop/JupeeGUIFiles 2/JUPEE_GUI_WINDOWS copy.py", line 750, in <module>
    top().top()
  File "/Users/kf9z/Desktop/JupeeGUIFiles 2/JUPEE_GUI_WINDOWS copy.py", line 418, in top
    lock().locked()
  File "/Users/kf9z/Desktop/JupeeGUIFiles 2/JUPEE_GUI_WINDOWS copy.py", line 338, in locked
    lock().unlocked()
  File "/Users/kf9z/Desktop/JupeeGUIFiles 2/JUPEE_GUI_WINDOWS copy.py", line 410, in unlocked
    setup().setdesk()
  File "/Users/kf9z/Desktop/JupeeGUIFiles 2/JUPEE_GUI_WINDOWS copy.py", line 191, in setdesk
    for o in os.listdir("/Users/"+getpass.getuser()+"/Desktop/"+jkjk+execfilepy):
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

This is Python 2.7 (or 2.x)

Comment: it's actually not telling which ones are and aren't executable, it's telling it

Comment: Instead of creating a list of empty strings, create an *empty* list and use `lis0.append()` to add new elements..

Comment: it's telling it this:     for however many extra icons are on the desktop:       go to the list0[] to find the directory that the icon points to.

Comment: What's with the variable names? `jkjk`? `aaas`? `fasdd`? `fttts`?

Answer (score 0):

You changed `jkjk` to a list here:

```
jkjk = os.listdir("/Users/"+getpass.getuser()+"/Desktop/"+jkjk)
```

And then you're trying to concatenate it to a string:

```
os.listdir("/Users/"+getpass.getuser()+"/Desktop/"+jkjk+execfilepy):
```

If you want the original `jkjk` then assign the list to some new variable:

```
jkjk = jkjk+"/Files/Executable"
lis = os.listdir("/Users/"+getpass.getuser()+"/Desktop/"+jkjk) 
for exfilepy in lis:
     #your code
```